# how to call in return inside of if statement's variable outside of statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement, return

```
if (condition works){
  let x = 20;
  let y= 30;
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
```

using react native:
I don't want to declare the variable outside the `if` condition so I use the `let` inside the `if` statement. Now, I want to call this outside of the `if` statement in `return ()`,

How can I call the `x`, `y` in `return` and get the values?

suppose:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>
       X:{x} & Y:{y} 
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: What language is this? Please [edit] your question to add the language as a tag.

Comment: And if you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In JavaScript, I already edit and mention in tag about language.

Comment: Then return inside if statement (and have another return outside)... If you can't do this than obviously x and y scope is to narrow and you should move them outside if statement... Where is the problem?

Comment: if i call them in outside of statement they are giving me first initial values likes 0 or null then it replace to modified values, so when i use the values it takes first values for display

Comment: is there don't have any option to call those variable in the outside of of statement?

Answer (score 0):

Akash Ghosh, this is not the right approach. You should save your x and y in useState, and show them if your condition is met, smt like this:

```
const [x,setX]=useState(null);
const [y,setY]=useState(null);
```

And in you function you just set the value:

```
    if(conditionMet){
     setX(20);
     setY(30);
    }
```

And in your rendering if you don't want to show them if they value didn't change you do this:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  { x && y ? <Text style={styles.text}>
    X:{x} & Y:{y} 
  </Text> :null }

  </View>
);

enter code here
```

Comment: it's given me an error which is  "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of orders to prevent ab infinite loop".

Comment: You need to call this function that changes state, only once. Maybe there is your problem. If you create sandbox I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 you can define like it  


function myfunction (){
    if (condition works){
                let x = 20;
                let y= 30;
                let data={x,y}
                return data
             }
}
```

and can use like it

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  { x && y ? <Text style={styles.text}>
    X:{myfunction().x} & Y:{myfunction().y} 
  </Text> :null }

  </View>
);
```